# How to add a TOC for each section and subsection before of each section in beamer?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sections-paragraphs

At the beginning of each section I want to add a table of content *without* the subsections **and** a table of content *with* the subsections. What can I do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.
You are probably looking for `minitoc` or `etoc` package

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87709/minitoc-of-a-subsection

Comment: Is this a beamer question actually?

Comment: Also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101206/beamer-mini-toc

Comment: You do not need any packages, you can achieve this with the build in optional arguments for `\tableofcontents` in beamer

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this with the optional arguments for `\tableofcontents` and the `\AtBeginSection`-command.

You can define the style for the sections and subsections like this:

`sectionstyle=<current section>/<other sections>`

`subsectionstyle=<current subsection>/<other subsections in current secton>/<other subsections>`

Valid keywords are `show`, `shaded` and `hide`

This places a Toc without subsections and one with the subsections of the current section at each section:

```
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}{title}
  \tableofcontents[
    sectionstyle=show/show,
    subsectionstyle=hide/hide/hide
  ]
  \end{frame}
  \begin{frame}{title}
  \tableofcontents[
    currentsection,
    sectionstyle=show/hide,
    subsectionstyle=show/show/hide
  ]
  \end{frame}
}
```

See page 99–­100 of the beamer user guide for explanation