# How to add a TOC of subsections at the beginning of each section in a book

Tags: titletoc

1. Right after *each* section title, I would like a partial TOC of the subsections in *that* section and *that* section only.

titledoc's

```
\startcontents[sections]
\printcontents[sections]{p-}{2}[2]
```

prints *all* the subsections in the chapter and I have not been able to figure out what to do.

I believe this was answered in [How to add a TOC for each section and subsection before of each section in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218940/how-to-add-a-toc-for-each-section-and-subsection-before-of-each-section-in-beame) but this is for a book.

2. I would assume that the purpose of `beamer`'s

   \AtBeginSection[]

is to avoid having to enter the commands at the beginning of each and every section and defining an equivalent newcommand in latex would be very nice.