# How to make a local TOC that only shows levels below where it is inserted?

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I simply want to make a local Table of Contents (TOC) which shows in its content what is below the level the TOC is inserted in and not outside.

For example, if I do `\minitoc` inside `\section{}`, the local TOC should only show the subsections and subsubsection inside this section.

Similarly, if I do `\minitoc` inside `\subsection{}`, the local TOC should only show the subsubsections inside this section.

But a TOC inside, say, a `subsection`, will show everything starting from the section above, to the end of the document! Which is very confusing.

I'll show an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that/231#231) and then show what I want:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{minitoc}        
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\begin{document}

\dominitoc                
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} %For the main TOC, only show chapter/section
\tableofcontents                 
\chapter{this is chapter heading}

  \section{this is section heading}
    \subsection{this is subsection heading}
    \setcounter{minitocdepth}{5}
    \minitoc %This TOC should only show the two subsubsection below!

       \subsubsection{this is subsubsection heading}
       \subsubsection{this is another subsubsection heading}

    \subsection{this is another subsection heading}
    \subsection{this is yet another subsection heading}

  \section{this is yet another section}
\end{document}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The idea is the the local TOC should only show what is in the lower level and no more. It acts as a guide of what is inside that section or subsection.

This way, I can make a local TOC in each section or subsection, which only shows what is below it, and it gets cut off when the level goes up automatically.

I hope there is a simple solution for this. I am open to others solutions using etoc or something else as long as the local TOC only shows what is inside that level as described above.

**Addition**

I tried to use [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87709/minitoc-of-a-subsection), but I do not understand the answer (too complicated for me) and how to use it for the above example. This is what I tried:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{minitoc} 
\usepackage{etoc}       
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\begin{document}    
%\dominitoc %Removed. switch to etoc
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} %For the main TOC, only show chapter/section
\tableofcontents         

\chapter{this is chapter heading}    
  \section{this is section heading}
    \subsection{this is subsection heading}
    %\setcounter{minitocdepth}{5} %Do not use now, we are using etoc
     \localtableofcontents

       \subsubsection{this is subsubsection heading}
       \subsubsection{this is another subsubsection heading}

    \subsection{this is another subsection heading}
    \subsection{this is yet another subsection heading} 
  \section{this is yet another section}
\end{document}
```

I get this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which is not what I want. If someone knows how to implement the solution shown in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87709/minitoc-of-a-subsection) for my small example above, it will be great. Again, I am not asking for fancy heading, fancy line styles, minipages, and all that. A simple local TOC is all I want.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87709/27635. I don't think `minitoc` can manage this.

Comment: @karlkoeller I actually saw the question you linked to, spend 2 hrs just trying to understand it and could it. If things has to be this complicated to make local toc in latex, then something is wrong here. I did not undertand all this `\makeatletter
\newif\ifTOC@marginpatched
\newcommand{\SetTOCrightmargin}[1]{%
\ifTOC@marginpatched\else
\let\old@pnumwidth\@pnumwidth
\let\old@dottedtocline\@dottedtocline
\def\@dottedtocline##1##2##3##4##5{%
    \old@dottedtocline{##1}{##2}{##3}{##4}{##5\hskip\TOC@rightmargin}}
\let\old@l@part\l@part
\def\l@part##1##2{\old@l@part{##1}{##2\hskip\TOC@rightmar..`

Comment: I need a simple solution that I can understand. Not asking for anything fancy. All solutions posted seems to be too complicated for some reason. May be it is the nature of Latex.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `etoc` package provides for a `\localtableofcontents` which can be configured in place with `\etocsettocstyle` and `etocsetnexttocdepth` commands

The visual appearance can be configured with `tocloft` commands.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoc}       
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\begin{document}    

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} %for main TOC, only show chapter/section
\tableofcontents
\chapter{this is chapter heading}    
  \section{this is section heading}
  \subsection{this is subsection heading}
    \etocsetnexttocdepth{5}
    \etocsettocstyle{\subsubsection*{Local contents}}{}
    \cftsubsubsecindent 0pt
    \localtableofcontents
    \subsubsection{this is subsubsection heading}
    \subsubsection{this is another subsubsection heading}

    \subsection{this is another subsection heading} % not shown
    \subsection{this is yet another subsection heading} % not shown
    \section{this is yet another section} %not shown
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Thanks to jfbu for his helpful comments **

Comment: another nice solution, thank you. Simple direct solution.

Comment: You may be interested in creating your own ToC style using `\etocsettocstyle`.

Comment: @Werner: Good point -- I will add some code tomorrow

Comment: The `\etocsetlevel{subsection}{1}` line is not needed. I would suggest also inserting for example `\etocsettocstyle{\subsubsection*{\contentsname{} for this subsection}}{}` right before the `\localtableofcontents`.

Comment: @jfbu: I have to trust the package author ;-) I wanted to add `\etocsettocstyle{...}` tomorrow...

Comment: The reason for the big left indentation is because this is inherited from how the subsubsections headings would be displayed by the document class. Package `tocloft` can be loaded for easy customizing of this. Just make sure it is loaded before `etoc`. It is also possible to use `etoc` for all the customizing one wishes, but this is admittedly harder on the standard user.

Comment: @jfbu: Yes, I wondered about that, I wanted to 'attack' also, but I had not much time ... it was a quick 'solution'.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer ;-) the `\etocsetlevel` is for advanced tricks.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer with `\usepackage{tocloft}` in the preamble and simply `\cftsubsubsecindent 0pt ` on a line before the `\localtableofcontents` the indentation is gotten rid of.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Hi, one last remark: currently `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` appears after the main `\tableofcontents`. But it should be before if you want it to influence the main TOC. This said, welcome to the world-wide community of `etoc` users! (we are two, no wait, three, now! I hear we are now four, no five! ...)

Comment: @jfbu: Who are the other three guys/girls? ;-) Thanks

Comment: I counted @Nasser then Christine who supervised the translation into German of `etoc.pdf`, then at least one member of her team, but I might be too optimistic ;-)

Answer (score 16):

I'm a big fan of `titletoc` instead of `minitoc`, (especially since I use `titlesec` all the time) and `titletoc` provides easy methods to do what you want.

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % just to make a nice image for the answer
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
\section{Section}
\startcontents[sections]
\printcontents[sections]{}{1}{}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\lipsum[1]
\stopcontents[sections]
\section{Section 2}
\startcontents[sections]
\printcontents[sections]{}{1}{}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\lipsum
\stopcontents[sections]
\chapter{Second chapter}
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
\section{Section}
\startcontents[sections]
\printcontents[sections]{}{1}{}
\lipsum[3]
\section{Another section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]