# Can I limit the scope of a ToC depth change for a local ToC? (\etocsettocdepth)

Tags: table-of-contents, grouping, etoc

I'd like to create local table of contents that list the subsections within a section as an itemized list. To do this, I used `etoc` and defined a style `\etocsetstyle` accordingly.

The problem is that by calling my local toc `\itemizedlocaltoc`, I also set the ToC depth globally by calling `\etocsettocdepth{subsection}`. This changes the depth of the bookmarks for the rest of the document: scope leak.

Is there a way to limit the scope of `\etocsettocdepth{subsection}`?

Relevant part of `etoc.sty` mentions `\global`, which would seem to imply "no".

```
\def\etocsettocdepth   {\futurelet\Etoc@nexttoken\Etoc@set@tocdepth }
\def\Etoc@set@tocdepth {\ifx\Etoc@nexttoken\bgroup
                            \expandafter\Etoc@set@tocdepth@
                       \else\expandafter\Etoc@set@toctocdepth
                       \fi }
\def\Etoc@set@tocdepth@ #1{\@ifundefined {Etoc@#1@@}
      {\PackageWarning{etoc}
          {Unknown sectioning unit #1, \protect\etocsettocdepth\space ignored}}
{\global\c@tocdepth\csname Etoc@#1@@\endcsname}%
```

## Bookmarks without `\listsubseclocaltoc`

[image]

## Bookmarks with `\listsubseclocaltoc`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% xelatex
\usepackage{etoc}% local toc mechanism
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\usepackage{hyperref}% get pdf bookmarks

\def\itemizedlocaltoc{% All settings, particularly \etocsettocdepth, should be local to this scope
% Available vars provided by etoc: \etocname \etocnumber \etocpage
\def\contentsname{}
\etocsettocstyle{\par\medskip}{}%\etocsettocstyle{beforetoc}{aftertoc}, use for heading
\etocsetstyle{subsection}
{\begin{itemize}}
{\scshape\item}
{\etocname{}}
{\end{itemize}}

%\etocsettocmargins[0mm]{0mm}{0mm}% custom margins for local toc https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87709/minitoc-of-a-subsection/87716
\begingroup
\etocsettocdepth{subsection} % set depth of this toc
\localtableofcontents
\endgroup
}%

\begin{document}
% Main Stuff
\section{Main Stuff}
\itemizedlocaltoc

% Sub stuff for demo
\newcount\step
\step=1
\loop% TeX loop for fun
\subsection{Substuff \the\step}
Here is a nice sentence about cool stuff \#\the\step.
\subsubsection{Subsubstuff \the\step}
\advance \step by 1
\ifnum\step<6
\repeat

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: there is  `\etocsetnexttocdepth`, you can try it.

Comment: @touhami That seemed to do the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Touhami mentioned `\etocsetnexttocdepth`, which solves the issue

## Definition of `\etocsetnexttocdepth`

```
\def\etocsetnexttocdepth #1{%
    \@ifundefined{Etoc@#1@@}
     {\PackageWarning{etoc}
       {Unknown sectioning unit #1, \protect\etocsetnextocdepth\space ignored}}
     {\edef\Etoc@aftertochook {\global\c@tocdepth\the\c@tocdepth\space
                              \let\noexpand\Etoc@aftertochook\noexpand\@empty }%
      \global\c@tocdepth\csname Etoc@#1@@\endcsname}%
}%
```

This definition differs from `\etocsettocdepth` by adding a hook that will be executed after each `etoc` table of contents. As shown in the code above, `\edef\Etoc@aftertochook` is set to the register containing the current ToC depth `\c@tocdepth` before the depth `\c@tocdepth` is changed.

Comment: Indeed, a `\global` is always done by LaTeX's `\setcounter{...}`, and `etoc` dutifully manipulates the LaTeX counter `tocdepth` similarly, although not using `\setcounter`. Thus the method is to store the current value and reset the tocdepth to this value afterwards. This is very useful when hyperref is present, because hyperref checks value of tocdepth for bookmarks. Thus setting `tocdepth` only temporarily in-between sectioning commands avoids any disturbance to hyperref.

Comment: Good note about `hyperref`. I don't want any disturbances.